# If $X$ is connected then there're not $F$ and $G$ such that $F\cap G=\emptyset$ and $X=F\cup G$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, connectedness

**Theorem:** Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. If there is no nonempty closed subsets $F$ and $G$ in $X$ such that $F\cap G=\emptyset$ and $X=F\cup G,$ then $X$ is connected.

Proof

Let's suppose X is no connected and let's see that there exist nonempty closed subsets $F$ and $G$ in $X$ such that $F\cap G=\emptyset$ and $X=F\cup G$.

As X is no connected, there exists open sets $U,V\in\tau$ such that $U\cap V=\emptyset$ , $X=U\cup V$ and both are nonempty sets...(1)

Notice that $U^c=V,V^c=U.$

Therefore  $U$ and $V$ are closed. And by (1) the proof is done.

I did this proof and I don't know if it's correct.
Could you check it and tell me please?

Comment: It is correct. Good work.

Comment: :)  I can be at peace now.

Comment: Nice proof by contrapositive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have $X = A \cup B$ where $A \cap B = \emptyset$, the following are equivalent:

1. $A$ and $B$ are both open.
2. $A$ and $B$ are both closed.
3. $A$ and $B$ are separated: $A \cap \overline{B}  =\overline{A} \cap B = \emptyset$.

You did the equivalence of 1. and  2. essentially: $A$ and $B$ are each other's complements so $A$ open iff $B$ closed and vice versa.

If $A$ and $B$ are separated, $A$ is closed: $A \subseteq \overline{A} \subseteq X\setminus B  =A$ and similarly $B$ is closed, so 3 implies 2. 2 implies 3 is trivial.

All 3 variants are taken (depending on the textbook) as the definition of a disconnected space (if both are non-empty too).

Comment: Good to know that, thanks Henno. What textbook would you recommend for self-learning topology?

Comment: @Isabella Munkres is quite good for self-study. A lot of its excercises are solved on this site (I think all of them are somewhere) which also helps when you're stuck. Also Willard, which is a lot cheaper.

Comment: "..all of them somewhere" , you know where they are.. :D  .Ok thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I think  your proof it's very good.