# Need help with Ex 3.3.3 from Topology Without Tears

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Let (X $\tau$) be any topological space

Prove that (X $\tau$) is not connected iff it has proper nonempty disjoint open subsets
A and B s.t $ A\cup B=X$

[image]
My ideas come from here

([If $X$ is connected then there're not $F$ and $G$ such that $F\cap G=\emptyset$ and $X=F\cup G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2540136/830852))

**Proof**
(l thought of proof by contradiction but
did not know how to proceed)

(<=)Suppose  we have proper nonempty disjoint
open subsets A an B s.t A$\cup $ B=X

As X is not connected ,$\exists  U \in\tau$
and.U=A B=X\U. So U is clopen

Then $\tau $ is nonconnected

How is this half of the proof

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the definition of "connected".

Comment: There it’s been done

Comment: I see where my mistakes is. Connectedness is opposite state to disjoint state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is not connected according to the definition you gave. So there is a clopen subset $C$ that is not euql to $X$ or $\emptyset$. Then note that $A=C$ and $B=X\setminus C$ are both open and disjoint and non-empty and $A \cup B=X$ is trivial.

If $A ,B$ are open disjoint and non-empty and $X=A\cup B$ then $A$ (and $B$ too) is clopen and unequal to $X$ or $\emptyset$. So $X$ is then not connected.

Comment: So how did I do

Comment: @Homer your idea makes no sense to me.

Comment: How is B open ?

Comment: Complement of $C$, which is closed. @Homer

Comment: Ok . In URL I quoted you mention. A,B separate,cl(A)$\cap$ B=A$\cap$cl(B)=0 l was trying to use it..

Comment: @Homer that’s a slightly different definition again. Based on separated sets.

Comment: Ok.l see.There should be a standard def.